# Filter array of 3-item arrays by third item; get result set without third items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have these variables:

```js
var arr = [
    [ "name1", 2, "filter1" ],
    [ "name2", 5, "filter2" ],
    [ "name3", 8, "filter3" ],
    [ "name4", 1, "filter2" ]
  ];

// This variable may have values: `"filter1"`, `"filter2"`, `"filter3"`.
var filter = "filter2";
```

How can I filter the array `arr` according to the `filter` variable values?

My example must return this:

```js
[
  [ "name2", 5 ],
  [ "name4", 1 ]
]
```

Comment: share some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the filtering, you need to get only the first two elements of the inner arrays.

[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns the same elements in the array. For getting the wanted items without the filter item, you need to return either the first two objects, or filter the items with the given filter as well (proposal 2).

```js
var array = [['name1', 2, 'filter1'], ['name2', 5, 'filter2'], ['name3', 8, 'filter3'], ['name4', 1, 'filter2']],
    filter = 'filter2',
    result = array.filter(a => a[2] === filter).map(a => a.slice(0, 2));
    
console.log(result);
```

```js
var array = [['name1', 2, 'filter1'], ['name2', 5, 'filter2'], ['name3', 8, 'filter3'], ['name4', 1, 'filter2']],
    filter = 'filter2',
    result = array
        .filter(a => a.some(v => v === filter))
        .map(a => a.filter(v => v !== filter));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

By using filter method you can easily test what you want and only return the match elements

```js
var arr = [['name1', 2, 'filter1'], ['name2', 5, 'filter2'],['name3', 8, 'filter3'], ['name4', 1, 'filter2']];

var filter = 'filter2';

var result = arr.filter(function(res){
  return res[2] == filter;
}).map(function(filtered){
  return filtered.slice(0,2);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think your answer is better than mine.

Comment: I think too cause yours doesn't work if a name have the same value than the filter

Comment: Sure.. Thats it!